# Owin.Testing.TestServer and attribute based routing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, owin

We are having the webservice that is using attribute based routing. Few examples of routes:

```
/api/v1/reporting/client
/api/v1/reporting/client/{id}
/api/v1/reporting/client/{id}/address/{addressId}
/api/v1/reporting/account
/api/v1/billing/client
/api/v1/billing/client/{id}
/api/v1/billing/client/{id}/transactions
```

Because of this structure we are using attribute based routing (each controller has RoutePrefix attribute and each method on it has Route attribute). At some point we started to convert it OWIN. Also we would like to use have a unit tests for most of our endpoints. So I ended up trying to use Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer. However any endpoint I'm trying to test I'm getting 404 and it looks like b/c we are using attributes for routing (when I tested this method on webapi that doesn't use attributes I do not have this issue). So my question is how can I make attribute based routing work with TestServer or how I can replace attributes with something else that will work with TestServer and provide me routes I listed earlier.

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work?

Comment: I'm using TestServer with attribute routing with no issues - so it's definitely possible, but not sure what your problem may be. Are you calling MapHttpAttributeRoutes when building your WebApi HttpConfig?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer, not yet. Didn't had a chance to come back to that project yet.

Comment: @danielrbradley, I'm calling "globalConfig.MapHttpAttributeRoutes( constraintResolver );" where HttpConfiguration globalConfig and DefaultInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver

Comment: Are you still having this problem? I ran into something similar where all my routes were prefixed with "api/". It turned out to be caused by the base address on `HttpClient` attached to the `TestServer`. I switched to instantiating my own `HttpClient` and set the base address my set which resolved the issue.